# Как установить telegram скрипт в React проекте?

Tags: reactjs, telegram-bot, telegram, webstorm

Как установить telegram скрипт в React проекте? не выпадает меню с Download library. window не содержит Telegram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.html:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Должно помочь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.